# Setting a double pointer array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, double-pointer

I know there are a lot of double pointer questions, but I couldn't find one that pertained to starting an array.

In the code below, I can set pointers in main by `ptrs[0] = &array[0];`, but the code halts when `enqueue()` calls `*queue[i] = p;`. Why is that? I don't know if it matters, but ptrs[] is not initialized.

```
#define QUEUE_LEN 5

int *ptrs[5];
int array[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};

void enqueue(int *p, int **queue) {
    int i = 0;
    int *tmp;

    // Find correct slot
    while (*queue && *queue[i] >= *p) {
        i++;
    }

    // Error no free slots
    if (i == QUEUE_LEN) {
        printf("No free slots.\r\n");
        return;
    }

    // Insert process
    if (!*queue) {
        *queue[i] = p;
        return;
    }
    else {
        tmp = *queue[i];
        *queue[i] = p;
    }

    // Increment the other processes

    return;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int i;
    for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
        enqueue(&array[i], ptrs);
    }

    for (i=0; i<QUEUE_LEN; i++)
        printf("%d\n", *(ptrs[i]));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code outright doesn't compile. In `*queue[i] = p` you are trying to assign a pointer to an integer.

Comment: Hmm... seems to compile on mine and it was a simple copy paste to here.

Comment: Then you should get a proper C compiler or try to crank up the warning level on yours. And even if it does compile, it does not do what you think it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After first loop, `i` will remain zero. Here:

```
if (!*queue) {
    *queue[i] = p;
    return;
}
```

You check, that `*queue` is 0 and dereference it as well. It is UB.

PS. Btw, this:

```
*queue[i] = p;
```

Will not compiles, since `*queue[i]` has type `int`, but `p` has type `int*`.

Comment: @EricFossum, Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Ahh thanks, so then my question would be. Is void enqueue(int *p, int **queue) correct? Or should it be like (int *)*queue (which doesn't compile)?

Comment: Haha good point, you're saying `*queue[i]` has type `int`, How do I make it `int*`?

Comment: @EricFossum, Hmm... Just don't dereference it?

Comment: OMG, now I feel dumb. Possibly the dumbest I've ever felt on here

Answer (score 0):

```
// Find correct slot
while (*queue && *queue[i] >= *p) {
    i++;
}
```

This will access some random memory address  taken from uninitialized `ptrs` value.
Your check for *queue != 0 is not enough, you need to initialize array with zeores as:

```
int *ptrs[5] = {0};
```

And you still need to allocate memory you are attempting to write later when inserting.

Comment: Exactly. Assign addresses to the pointers in the array first.